# MySQL: Multiple Counts within the same LEFT JOIN table not working

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have these 3 tables:

```
1. posts (num, title, createdDate)
2. comments (num, post_num, parent_comment)
3. likes (comment_num)
```

I am trying a query to get the following results:

```
1. all posts
2. comments count including replies
3. replies count only (comments.parent_comment != 0)
4. total likes count
5. total participants in a post
```

So far i am good with everything except the #3, i.e. replies count only (comments.parent_comment != 0)

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
posts.num, 
posts.title, 
DATEDIFF(NOW(),posts.createdDate) as NumOfDays,
COUNT( comments.num)  AS totalComments,
COUNT( CASE WHEN comments.parent_comment=0 THEN 0 ELSE comments.parent_comment END)  AS totalReplies,


COUNT( likes.comment_num  ) AS totalLikes,
COUNT( DISTINCT comments.member_num)  AS participants,
cms_uploads.urlPath

FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_num = posts.num
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.comment_num = comments.num


GROUP BY posts.num
ORDER BY totalComments DESC
```

The result i am having is **"totalReplies"** count is similar to **"totalComments"** count.

Any ideas how can i get this to work by getting correct totalReplies count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() will count zeros. Use SUM(), a la:

```
SUM( CASE WHEN comments.parent_comment = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS totalReplies,
```

Comment: i just found a little problem, its the `totalReplies` value is always coming 1, even if there is no comment placed on a post, `totalReplies` comes out as 1 instead of 0. Any ideas?

Comment: to be more precise, if the `totalComments` count is 0 then `totalReplies` count becomes 1. And if the `totalComments` count is > 0 then `totalReplies` count works fine and shows 0 or the correct # of replies.

Comment: Try "CASE WHEN comments.parent_comment = 0 AND comments.parent_comment IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a couple things going on here. The structure of your case statement as mentioned above could use a reworking

```
SELECT 
posts.num, posts.title, urlpath(? dont see this in any table),  DATEDIFF(NOW(),posts.createdDate) as NumOfDays, 
SUM( comments.num)  AS totalComments,
SUM( CASE WHEN comments.parent_comment=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS totalReplies,
SUM( likes.comment_num  ) AS totalLikes,
COUNT( DISTINCT comments.member_num)  AS participants, 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_num = posts.num
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.comment_num = comments.num
GROUP BY posts.num, posts.title, NumOfDays
ORDER BY totalComments DESC
```

Try this. It takes care of your selective group by, and your COUNT misinterpretation on CASE struct.

Comment: thank you for the solution, but that @nw answer was quick to apply.

Comment: i just tried your solution (as @nw's solution is having a little problem with showing totalReplies min always 1 instead of showing 0 where there is none), your solution is doubling totalComments and totalReplies count. Any ideas?

Comment: because your group by wasn't taking into consideration the posts.title, and the NumOfDays...you can take those out of group by, but in most cases you want to group by everything before the aggregate, which in this case is, SUM(comments_num) as totalComments...you should have a check query that will confirm the numbers you want, and then choose a group by that correlates to those figures.